# In Finder, first tag vanishes while adding a second tag

Tags: macos, finder, finder-tag

- MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2011)
- macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G7024)

This is a problem I've been having since Mavericks first came out, and it has persisted through at least two complete OS reinstalls (though always on the same hardware).

Suppose I open a PDF in Preview. If I click on the file name in the title bar, I get the little drop-down dialogue that lets me change the file name, tags and location:

[image: file_properties_dialogue]

I can start typing in the 'tags' field, and add a tag either by autocompleting an existing tag or by typing the name of a new one. Once I've finished typing this tag or selected an autocompleted tag, I press return and the tag is 'locked in':

[image]

If I then start to enter a second tag, about 75% of the time, the first tag will vanish after I've typed the first 3-4 letters of the second tag:

[image]

In this picture, it looks like I've deleted the first tag, but I haven't: I've just started typing the second tag and the first one spontaneously vanished on its own. Usually, I have to re-enter the first tag two or three times before it 'sticks'.

The issue occurs in any app with the 'document model' drop-down in the menu bar.

This behaviour has been driving me nuts for nearly six years. Is there any way to fix it?

[This person seems to have had the same problem, but no solution was posted](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5618780)

Answer (score 1):

Not seeing the tag in the tag-line is not a proof the tag is not there.
Try moving the cursor while it is in the tag-line (like it is seen in the second of your screenshots) using the left arrow keyboard key. In my case I can scroll that way through all my attached tags.